# Passing the URL/route parameter from laravel and using in angular

Tags: angularjs, routes, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 and angular. 
I am using Laravel routing for traversal and backend operations and angular for just UI operations like fetching data and binding UI grid, etc.

I have following route defined in routes.php file below

**routes.php**

```
Route::pattern('clientid', '[0-9]+');

//used for AJAX call from angularjs and populating ui-grid
Route::get('getclients/{clientid?}', 'ClientController@getClients');

//used for displaying Laravel view with ui-grid
Route::get('client/{clientid?}', 'ClientController@showClients');
```

Please find the angular files:

**app.js**

```
var appClients = angular.module('getclients', ['clientsService', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.selection']);
```

**clientController.js**

```
appClients.controller('ClientsController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Client', '$interval', '$q', function ($scope, $http, Client, $interval, $q) {
/* Defining UI grid options*/
.
.
/* Calling service to fill the grid*/
Client.get(clientid)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                    }
                });
}
```

**clientsService.js**

```
angular.module('clientsService', [])
        .service('Client', function ($http) {
            return {
                // Get all the photos
                get: function (clientid) {
                    if (clientid !== '') {
                        return $http.get('/myproject/public/getclients/' + clientid);
                    }
                    else {
                        return $http.get('/myproject/public/getclients/');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
/*
    **Note:**
    Have already defined route in routes.php for using the same above:    
    Route::get('getclients/{clientid?}', 'ClientController@getClients');
*/
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Step 1:
Say I am hitting URL: http://<domain>/public/myproject/client/2

The following route would catch it and redirect to view where the ui-grid is present
    Route::get('client/{clientid?}', 'ClientController@showClients');

Step 2:        
    Now, somehow need to figure out how to pass that **2** to angular so that I could pass that parameter while making ajax call and get grid data
```

I am confused as to how we could use the the url parameter from Laravel in angular?

I reckon that I am missing some concept or doing something wrong here.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Why not getting url param and do http call to your controller and get it done ?

Comment: Unable to get you. We need to get URL param somehow in angular before http call.

Comment: Can't get `routeParams` ?

Comment: Haven't used `ng-Route` as there are no angular pages. So how can I get `routeParams` without using `ng-Route`?

Comment: Then is that ok for you to use jquery in that particular area ?

Comment: If it is possible to do via angular it would be great. But if not then pass variable in view and user jquery /javascript to assign the value passed from view and pass it in angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a workaround to make it work with angular and without jquery.**

From routes.php, the control is transferred to showClients action in ClientsController.php

**ClientsController.php (Laravel Controller):**

Passed the variable to Laravel view from controller using following statement:

```
public function showClients($clientid = '') {
 return view('masters.clients', compact('clientid'));
}
```

**Clients.php (Laravel View)**

Added clientidmodel as `ng-model` and initialized it with passed clientid from Laravel controller using `ng-init`

```
<div ng-app="">
   <div ng-controller="ClientsController">
       <input type="text" name="txtClientId" ng-model="clientidmodel" style="display: none;" ng-init="clientidmodel = '{!!$clientid!!}'"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

**clientController.js**

Added the watch to the angular model so that we can capture the initial value passed.

```
$scope.$watch("clientidmodel", function () {
           Client.get($scope.clientidmodel)
                   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                       if (data.length > 0) {
                           $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                       }
                   });
       });
```

Not sure whether this is the efficient way but as of now got the things working with this workaround.

Please let me know in case of any better way to approach the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in jquery by

```
var pathname = window.location.href;
var lastItem = pathname.split("/").pop(-1);
```

**Note :** Here you will get the last element

i.e.,

If your url is like `yourapp.com/app#/product/15` then the script will return `15`. That's the last element after `/` . You can change this according to your wish.

Then you can pass the value directly inside your Laravel Controller.

```
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'text',
    crossOrigin : true,
    data: {param : lastItem},
    url: serviceUrl+'/getReceipeDetails',
})
    .done(function( data ) {
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(result.success==1)
        {
        $(".yourresult").html('Controller return success');
        }
        else
        {
        $(".yourresult").html('Controller return failure');
        }
    })
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```